# Made an .exe in Visual C++ 2010, but it needs Microsoft.VC90.CRT to run

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I tried to run my .exe on different environments. I am installing the vcredist_x86.exe runtimes of VC++ 2010 express. But i get this error upon start. Why do i need the 2008 runtimes, too?

```
"Resolve Partial Assembly failed for Microsoft.VC90.CRT. Reference error message: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system."
```

Comment: Maybe you used 2010 developer studio but your project used 2008 tools to build the project? I believe that is a possibility. Check your C++ settings to verify toolchain.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My platform toolset is set to "v100" not "v90". I also need the 2010 runtimes to run the exe. Maybe i am using some vc90 functions in my code? Is this even possible?

Comment: Also i am ignoring default libs: LIBCMT.lib; LIBCMTD.lib

Comment: Nothing built with 2010 requires the 2008 runtime.  Are you linking against any 3rd party library which requires the 2008 runtime?  You can use depends or dumpbin /imports with your EXE to find its dependencies.

Comment: Yes, must be something like this.